# What is the time complexity of Summing Triples with duplicates?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Summing Triples problem is [strongly $NP$-complete](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/people/academic_staff/colin_mcdiarmid/?a=4138) as shown by McDiarmid.

**Summing Triples problem**:

Input: list of 3N **distinct** positive integers

Question: Is there a partition of the list into N triples $(a_i, b_i, c_i)$ such that $a_i + b_i= c_i$ for each triple $i$?

The condition that all numbers must be **distinct** makes the problem interesting and McDiarmid calls it a *surprisingly troublesome* .

> If the input is a *multiset* of positive integers, What is the complexity of Summing Triples? Does it remain NP-complete?

May be I overlooked an easy reduction from the original problem.